# Is AEM TarMK syncing bundles?

Tags: synchronization, aem, bundles

there is a *primary author* node1 which is used for installations, and then there is a *coldstandby author* node2 which is synchronised via TarMK. The crx3tar process is active on both node1 and node2, the new content/tars are added to the datastore and segmentstore on a daily basis. However, there is a substantial difference between the *primary* node1 and the *coldstandby* node2 regarding **bundles** and their versions displayed at `/system/console/bundles`.
On *coldstandby* node2 the versioning has fallen behind and some **bundles** are not present at all.

1. Does TarMK also synchronise this information?
2. If the bundles are not up to date then is it possible that other information is not properly synchronised?
3. Is there any way to check the status of the contents of *coldstandby* node2 by starting it without interfering with primary node1?

While the information in journal.log seems in order, **bundles** are not.
I have checked the documentation but cannot find any confirmation about bundles.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards

Comment: Okay, it turns out that bundles are updated at the last time the node was started as primary. So all your bundles are syncing but you can't see them until you switch between the two authors' nodes. AEM documentation is not covering this.